# How to schedule an ADF Pipeline to run mutiple hours daily?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can we schedule and ADF V1 Pipeline to run 4 times daily at  6:30 am, 9:30 am, 12:30 pm, and 3:30 pm???

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you,you could mark it for answer,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

ADF V2 [Schedule Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) is what you want.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot. You need to have an even distribution. You can run every four hours, but not limited to half a day. The nearest you can come with the standard tooling is 06:30, 09:30, 12:30, 15:30, 18:30, 21:30, 00:30, 03:30.

Comment: How about building seprate pipelines for all 4 different times

Comment: Yeah. You could just replicate 4x daily schedules and adjust the start times.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ADF V1, based on statement in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#dataset-availability), it's hard to implement your requirements.No such features could be rely on.

However, I provide you with a workaround that you could use [Azure Time Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) because it supports [CRON expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions). Please set the expression as `"0 30 6-15/3 * * *"` so that it could be triggered as your description. Then in the function code,you could fill the adf pipeline sdk execution code.

Of course, if you want to navigate to ADF V2, it has been already described in @Fang Liu's answer.